# Overwrite template of sales_email_order_items?

Tags: template, magento-1

I am always confused by Magento's template hierarchy. Within my email template, I can find this path:

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

I navigate to my themes folder in `app/design/frontend/default/ves_fashion/layout` and cannot find the `sales.xml`. Thats why I go to `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout` and see the `sales.xml`. Inside this xml file I look for "sales_email_order_items".

```
   <sales_email_order_items>
        <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
```

I can find the template files in the folder `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/`

I read that I just have to copy the default.phtml and the totals.phtml in the same path for my theme which is `app/design/frontend/default/ves_fashion/layout` but when I do this nothing changes. Why? Do I have to copy the `sales.xml` to my themes folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there,

If you look on the xml handle configuration you can find the path of temaplte for the email `<block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">` the path of emails templates are under base/default/template/email/order/*

Please try to duplicate that path on you theme and let me know.

Best,
ALe.

Comment: that works. Thanks. Puh, thats so confusing in Magento. It seems this file is existing 1000 times...I mean if i want to change the totals.phtml I have to copy it from /templates/sales to templates/email?

Comment: Cool! @Torben, feel free to ask anything else I glad to help you.